# Find out what account an application runs as

Tags: permissions, process, tomcat

Im in the middle of trying to set up a tomcat environment on my development machine. Im having trouble running applications, and it looks like its down to file permissions. The directory containing the application is inside my home directory. How can i find out:

- what account tomcat runs as
- how to create a new group for tomcat
- how to add tomcat to that group

in order that i can add application specific permissions to my home directory.

Answer (score 5):

#### Finding the user running tomcat

If you currently have tomcat running, then you can run ps and see what user a program is running as.

```
ps auxw | grep tomcat
```

This should list the processes that have the name tomcat (and the grep process, but ignore that). The first column of data is the user under which the command is run. For example, finding `apache` on my machine:

```
user@hostname ~$ ps auxw|grep apache
root       <numbers> ?        Ss   Nov10   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   <numbers> ?        S    Nov10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   <numbers> ?        Sl   Nov10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   <numbers> ?        Sl   Nov10   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
user       <numbers> pts/2    S+   11:22   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Thus here user that you would be interested in is `www-data`

#### Creating a new tomcat group

The program you want for this is `addgroup`

```
addgroup tomcat_group_name
```

#### Adding user that runs tomcat to group

For this step we will use `usermod`. The username will be what we got from the first step (in my example `www-data`). For this part I will just call it `tomcatuser`

```
usermod -a -G tomcat_group_name tomcatuser
```